# Initialize Loader when tab is selected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

Hi i am using `ViewPager` with `tab layouts`. I have two `fragments` for three tabs i.e `MoviesFragment` for tabs 1 and 2 and `FavoritesFragement` for tab 3.
Now in tabs 1 and 2 i select movies as favorites and show them in 3 tab by getting favorites movies from database using loaders.
Now `View pager` loads `FavroitesFragment` before tab is selected i.e one before and after and hence i fail to get updated data from database.
I used this in `onPageSelected()` method:

```
 @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Utility.setTabOpacity(tabLayout, position);
            switch(position){
                case 2:
                    FavoritesFragment fragment = (FavoritesFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
                       fragment.callMethod();
            }
        }
       //Here's callMethod() where i initialize loader
     public void callMethod(){
    //Starting loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

But I got `Fragment is not attached to activity` exception. I have also set `view pager` limit to 1 or 0 but that doesn't work.How to solve this problem?